# Jquery remove class isn't truely removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

```
var newLevel = function(level){
setTimeout(function(){
var time=2;
for(var i=1;i<level+1;i++){
    var box = parseInt(Math.random()*25+1)
    if($("#box"+box).hasClass("g3")){
        i--
    }else{
    $("#box"+box).removeClass();
    $("#box"+box).addClass("g3");
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){
        $(".g3").addClass("g2");
        $(".g3").removeClass("g3");
        var right = 0;
        var toGet = level
        $(".g2").click(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("g2");
            $(this).addClass("g3");
            right++
            if(right==toGet){
                level++;
                gameBoard(level)
                newLevel(level);
            }
        })
    },time*1000);
},2800);

}
```

So i am making a game, as usual, but i've run into a problem, as always. The `error` that is occurring I think comes from the `"click" event` when `.g2` is `clicked`, `visibly` the `.g2 class` is removed and `th` `.g3` `class` becomes `visible`. But after this `event` you can `re-click` the same `div` (previously having `.g2` now `visibly` having `.g3`) and have the same affect occur (`right++`) so it seems like `.g2` has not truly been removed? anyway's would love some help, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query in jQuery's click function isn't *live*, once event handler has been attached it won't be removed if DOM element changes (in your case when you remove the class). Imagine to register a click handler for N elements with class then you remove that class from half of them. All of them will still handle that event because click handler has been attached.

You should use `one()` function instead of `click()`:

```
$(".g2").one("click", (function() {
```

It works because you register a click handler then you remove class (and you don't want click handler any more). This is what `one()` does, event handler is executed just once (so you don't need any live query for this).

Answer (score 0):

I think the elements with class g2 will always have this onclick, even after you remove the class. This is expected. One workaround is to first check if "this" has class g2 before running the code:

```
$(".g2").click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.hasClass("g2")){
                $this.removeClass("g2");
                $this.addClass("g3");
                right++
                if(right==toGet){
                    level++;
                    gameBoard(level)
                    newLevel(level);
                }
            }
        })
```

But if the class g2 is never re-added, then Adriano's answer is better :)